# Inheritance - overriding mutator methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

So, let's say I have the following classes:

#### Foo

```
abstract class Foo{
    .
    .
    .
    public void setKey(FooKey key){
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

#### Bar

```
final class Bar extends Foo{
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void setKey(BarKey key){ // Can't do this?
        super.setKey(key);
    }
}
```

In the above example, `BarKey` is a subclass of `FooKey`. Here I want to ensure that the key that is set for `Bar` is a specific subclass of `FooKey` (i.e. `BarKey`). How do I go about this? Am I making this overly complicated? Is there a better design approach?

Comment: I am no expert on inheritance, but isn't it so that your method signatures do not match with one another, and this wouldnt compile? perhaps using `instaceof` could help?

Comment: @posdef, Yes, this won't compile (hence the "Can't do this"). And yes, I know I could use `instanceof`, but that's usually a sign of poor OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't correct, because you're making the subclass more restrictive than the superclass: the superclass makes it possible to set any kind of FooKey, but the subclass only accepts BarKey.

In order to do this, you need to make the superclass generic:

```
abstract class Foo<K extends FooKey> {
    private K key;

    public void setKey(K key){
        this.key = key;
    }
}

final class Bar extends Foo<BarKey> {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't enforce it that way.  Consider:

```
Bar b = new Bar();
FooKey k = new FooKey();
b.setKey(k);  // You want to prohibit this
Foo f = b;
f.setKey(k);  // But there's no way to prohibit this
```

In general, a derived class can't offer a *more* restrictive interface than its superclass.

So I would suggest removing `setKey` from the abstract class.

Comment: Good explanation. I was wondering if your last sentence there could be generalized as a rule of thumb, as in, "it's generally a bad idea to have specific setters in abstract classes"?

Comment: @posdef: I don't think so.  The problem isn't setters, it's that the OP is violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 2):

You should read about difference between overriding and overloading. The thing you did is simply overloading because you change the argument type which is not allow with overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `@Override` annotation as you're not overriding the method of the super class, (should be same arguments), you're just defining a new `setKey` method with a narrower type. This new setKey method will be accessible only through a `Bar` reference, however.